# Imprimir comunicacion web service

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy haciendo un Web Service y quiero imprimir las tramas de comunicacion que ingresan y la respuesta que sale.

Realizo el web service con el wizar de Netbeans con contener Tomcat y se realizo con la libreria Metro.

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "test")
public class test {

    /**
    * Web service operation
    */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "largo")
    public String largo(@WebParam(name = "palabras") String[] palabras) {
        System.out.println("tam" + palabras.length);
        return "Tam " + palabras.length;
    }
}
```

La idea es imprimir las tramas de comunicacion cuando realizo la consulta de los servicio ver las peticiones (informacion) que se envia y su respuesta a nivel de trasas XML asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradesco cualquier ayuda